# How could I make a Go program use more memory? Is that recommended?

Tags: go, memory-management

I'm looking for option something similar to `-Xmx` in Java, that is to assign maximum runtime memory that my Go application can utilise. Was checking the [runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStatsType) , but not entirely if that is the way to go.

I tried setting something like this with func SetMaxStack(), (likely very stupid)

```
debug.SetMaxStack(5000000000) // bytes
model.ExcelCreator()
```

The reason why I am looking to do this is because currently there is ample amount of RAM available but the application won't consume more than 4-6% , I might be wrong here but it could be forcing GC to happen much faster than needed leading to performance issue.

What I'm doing

Getting large dataset from RDBMS system , processing it to write out in excel.

Another reason why I am looking for such an option is to limit the maximum usage of RAM on the server where it will be ultimately deployed.

Any hints on this would greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?  It sounds like your program just isn't using as much memory as you expect--but why is that problematic?

Comment: Go will use the amount of memory it needs, what are you expected to take up the memory if the program doesn't need it?

Comment: @Flimzy issue i'm trying to address is the performance of excel generation, i have optimised my PSQL (the RDBMS currently used by my go application) relation to the point that it returns 3.5million rows within few seconds, however when processing this dataset in go (basically into excel's Row/Column format) to generate excel out of it, takes huge amount of time. Like ~8mins or so for half a million rows and 7 columns

Comment: @sup: the only trade-off you could make is to allow GC to use more memory, but you first need to determine if GC is your bottleneck in the first place

Comment: Have it piecemeal. Start with disabling Excel-everything first—that is, just crunch the data and throw the results away (not literally—make sure you, say, `fmt.Print()` them into `io/ioutil.Discard` for the compiler to not optimize your code away completely), and measure how it goes. If it's slow, _profile,_ or at least come up with a simple MCVE for us to squint at your code.

Comment: @JimB As mentioned in my question, and i may be wrong about it, but i think that since go is not really using much memory and likely trying to work with limited (if there is a default memory consumption defined) memory and calling GC too often .

Comment: So, in the end, this question appears as a classical case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). @sup, please consider first breaking your problem down into logical pieces—fetching data from the DBMS, processing it, making an Excel document of it,—then profile, then try to come up with different question(s) with the concrete problems you will have identified by then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current stable Go (1.10) has only a single knob which may be used to trade memory for lower CPU usage by the garbage collection the Go runtime performs.
This knob is called `GOGC`, and its description reads

> The `GOGC` variable sets the initial garbage collection target percentage. A collection is triggered when the ratio of freshly allocated data to live data remaining after the previous collection reaches this percentage. The default is `GOGC=100`. Setting `GOGC=off` disables the garbage collector entirely. The `runtime/debug` package's `SetGCPercent` function allows changing this percentage at run time. See https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetGCPercent.

So basically setting it to `200` would supposedly double the amount of memory the Go runtime of your running process may use.

Having said that I'd note that the Go runtime actually tries to adjust the behaviour of its garbage collector to the workload of your running program and the CPU processing power at hand.
I mean, that normally there's nothing wrong with your program not consuming lots of RAM—if the collector happens to sweep the garbage fast enough without hampering the performance in a significant way, I see no reason to worry about: the Go's GC is
one of the points of the most intense fine-tuning in the runtime,
and works *very* good in fact.

Hence you may try to take another route:

- Profile memory allocations of your program.
  Analyze the profile and try to figure out where the hot spots
  are, and whether (and how) they can be optimized.

  You might start [here](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)
  and continue with the gazillion other
  [intros](https://www.google.com/search?q=profiling+go+programs) to this stuff.
- Optimize. Typically this amounts to making certain buffers
  reusable across different calls to the same function(s)
  consuming them, preallocating slices instead of growing them
  gradually, using `sync.Pool` where deemed useful etc.

  Such measures may actually increase the memory
  truly used (that is, by live objects—as opposed to
  garbage) but it may lower the pressure on the GC.

Comment: `-Xmx` isn't really related to GC though, it's just the max heap size, which of course you can't really adjust in Go.

Comment: @JimB, sure, but a more relevant knob is likely to appear—see the [sort-of announce](https://blog.golang.org/ismmkeynote) and [the relevant issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16843). It won't be about limiting the heap usage (which is useless anyway—as any seasoned Java developer knows from hard-won experience) but rather about providing feedback to the running program about reaching the memory limits.

Comment: @kostix thank you for the explanation, this defintely helps in furthering my understanding. Will be working on what you suggested / commented above.